# htaccess redirect urls to specific urls

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, joomla-sef-urls

I have Old URLs in my site and it like this:

```
http://'www.example.com/newsroom/press-release/item/949-ItemAlias.html
```

I want to redirect it to :

```
http://'www.example.com/press/ItemAlias.html
```

I used this sentence in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^newsroom/press-release/item/(.*)$ /press/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

But this sentence redirect the URLs to `http://'www.example.com/press/949-ItemAlias.html` Of course the (949-) is example, I want to remove the number and dash when i redirect the URLs. What is the changes i have to do in .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

Your regex should match the number, but not include it in the ()'s.  ex:

```
RewriteRule ^newsroom/press-release/item/[0-9]*-(.*)$ /press/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

The `[0-9]*` matches an arbitrary length number, followed by the `-`.  Only what's matched parens will be included in `$1`.